# How to prevent a form value(s) reset in struts 1?

Tags: struts-1, struts-validation

I am trying to prevent the values of my select boxes on a jsp page being reset in struts 1. Not necessarily with new forms that are yet to submit the captured data, but forms filled from stored objects have their select fields reset to defaults which is causing undesirable effects to workflow as assumptions were being made that the values were kept.
I have found nothing so far in my search and would appreciate pointers/help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!! Setting the action that populates the JSP to session scope in the struts-config.xml action mapping solved my problem.

Comment: You should be avoid session-scoped form beans (in fact any session-scope variable) if possible as they can cause trouble. As an example: if a user opens two tabs in their browser then each will share the same session. If they visit your form in both tabs then the data they enter will conflict.

Comment: I know. I may already be seeing the side effect of this. But this is the only way I know at the moment for preserving form data.

Comment: Can you not persist the values (e.g. in a database) in the action that executes when the user submits the form and then retrieve them in the action that sets up the page next time? That's a fairly standard way of doing it

Comment: @MartinWilson is it okay to to create a new table to persist those data?

Comment: @MartinWilson The values are already persisted in the database. I'm talking about form resets in struts 1.

Comment: Do you mean you have a reset button in your form (input type="reset") or the JS formReset()?

Comment: no no. I mean whenever the form was reset, if there was an error on the page the actionform reset wiped every thing and reset a lot of values to to defaults, which is not a desired behaviour especially with already saved data.

Comment: @MartinWilson I know the problem u mentioned about two tabs but I cannot understand the solution (persist the session-scoped formvalue to db?)

Comment: Why are you calling reset when there is a validation error? The usual lifecycle of a form is that it is request scoped so it contains the values the user enters and keeps them if the user is returned to the same page e.g. on a validation error (as that's all part of the same request lifecycle)